# Vimeo video showing Private video message on public website

Tags: video, authentication, private, vimeo

We have vimeo videos embed in our public website. These videos where shown to visitors are expected. However, today discovered that videos are showing message 'Private Video' 'Login to watch (if you have permission)'
[image]

Tried looking for forum / online support for this. However, not able to get any link for this.

Kindly let know what needs to be done.

thank you

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Without a link to the page where the video is embedded or a link to the video, it's impossible to troubleshoot.

You'll need to review your video's playback privacy and embed privacy settings. An overview of video privacy settings is on Vimeo's Help Center here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview

You can contact Vimeo Support by logging into your account and going through the contact form here: https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Answer (score 0):

Open the video. On the right there is a setting for "Privacy". Click this. Look for the tab called "Content" and then set the rating to "All audiences". That does it.